# Django Amazon aws readonly database error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have developed a Django project on a local server using PyCharm with Apache server. Now I deployed project on the Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but when I am trying to register a User (using standard django User model) I get exception:

> attempt to write a readonly database

Can anyone give a hint how can I fix this?

Comment: Not familiar with Elastic Beanstalk, but can you do a simple run python runserver on the AWS host and see if it will work?

Comment: @JC203 yeah, the server is running and it's completely ok. However I can't write into databases